# custom Yii validation class

Tags: yii

I've created this custom class to validate some numbers on my website.

```
class EPriceValidator extends CValidator
{


        public $number_type;

        /*
         * Regular Expressions for numbers
         */ 
        private $default_pattern = '/[^0-9,.]/';
        private $price_pattern = '/[^0-9,.]/';

        /*
         * Default error messages
         */ 
         private $default_msg = '{attribute} is an invalid number.';
         private $price_msg = '{attribute} is an invalid price.';

        /**
         * Validates the attribute of the object.
         * If there is any error, the error message is added to the object.
         * @param CModel $object the object being validated
         * @param string $attribute the attribute being validated
         */
        protected function validateAttribute($object,$attribute)
        {
            // check the strength parameter used in the validation rule of our model
            if ($this->number_type == 'price')
            {
              $pattern = $this->price_pattern;
              $error_message = $this->price_msg;
            }
            else {
                $pattern = $this->default_pattern;
                $error_message = $this->default_msg;    
            }

            // extract the attribute value from it's model object
            $value=$object->$attribute;
            if(!preg_match($pattern, $value))
            {
                $this->addError($object,$attribute, $error_message);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Implementing Client Validation
         *
         * Returns the JavaScript needed for performing client-side validation.
         * @param CModel $object the data object being validated
         * @param string $attribute the name of the attribute to be validated.
         * @return string the client-side validation script.
         * @see CActiveForm::enableClientValidation
         */
        public function clientValidateAttribute($object,$attribute)
        {

            // check the strength parameter used in the validation rule of our model
            if ($this->number_type == 'price')
            {
              $pattern = $this->price_pattern;
              $error_message = $this->price_msg;
            }
            else 
            {
                $pattern = $this->default_pattern; 
                $error_message = $this->default_msg;
            }  

            $condition="value.match(".$pattern.")";

            return "
            if(".$condition.") {
                messages.push(".CJSON::encode($error_message).");
            }
            ";
        }
    }
```

it works fine. but how do i make it display the correct field name of the error? right now when there is an error detected on client side, the `clientValidateAttribute()` displays

```
{attribute} is an invalid number.
```

instead of

```
Total orders is an invalid number.
```

where `Total orders` is the input field that is in valid.

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rechecked this in the Yii [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CValidator#addError-detail), and it seems you have to add an array with parameters to replace the placeholders in your string. But if you only use the default placeholder for the attribute, it should work by default.

Do you have only the problem on client validation? Because I now checked also the Yii code, and it seems that your code is right, and should work (at least the server validation). But in the client validation you just pass the error mesasage to JSON without any processing, so the `{attribute}` is not replaces anywhere.
Try to add this to youc client validation before the `return`

```
$params['{attribute}']=$object->getAttributeLabel($attribute);
$error_message = strtr($error_message,$params));
```